# Another package being selected instead of what I am trying

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

I am trying to install dhcp3-server,but it is instead selecting isc-dhcp-server and its not working as per my expectations. Please help.

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Note, selecting 'isc-dhcp-server' instead of 'dhcp3-server'
```

I am following [How To Set Up A DHCP Server For Your LAN](http://www.howtoforge.com/dhcp_server_linux_debian_sarge) on the HowtoForge site.

There is nothing like dhcp3 in /etc/init.d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

isc-dhcp-server is the new name for the dhcp3-server package, so this is behaving as expected. Debian sarge is fairly old, so you can expect that tutorial to be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

The `isc-dhcp-server` is marked as `Provides: dhcp3-server`. The [`Provides`](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-virtual) relationship indicates that the `isc-dhcp-server` offers the same functionality as the `dhcp3-server` and can be installed in its place. The `isc-dhcp-server` package is essentially a new version of `dhcp3-server` under a different name.

The name of the service script reflects the name of the package: it's `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server`.